# Trouble with cwRsync on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, backup, rsync, cygwin

I have just setup cwRsyncServer on my 2008 server, it is permitted by the firewall, and I have configured a module with write access. The rsync server is running and listening.

I have cnfigured an ssh keypair, and placed the public key in authorized_keys on the server.

From the client, I am trying this command with the new file test.txt

```
rsync -av test.txt windowsaccount@192.168.1.1:/test.txt
```

On the server I have no recorded error and nothing in the logfile, on the client I get a connection timed out error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I troubleshoot it? Is it something to do with Windows credentials?

Comment: Is sshd running on the Windows server? Is port 22 really open? Timeouts on the client side suggest that connection attempts are being dropped/blocked by the server.

Comment: Do I need ssh? I have not specified to use ssh on the command line, so why would it require it?

Comment: On most modern platforms, `rsync` defaults to using `ssh` to create its communications channels to remote hosts. For more information about this, check the rsync man page.

Comment: @steven-monai: cwRsync is a repackaging of rsync and cygwin, and installs the server component as a service in daemon mode. I think the sample config file it ships doesn't use ssh, but it's been a while since I used cwRsync.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you set up cwRsyncServer in daemon mode, though, without seeing the configuration file, I cannot be sure. To use `rsync` to connect to a rsync daemon in daemon mode, use

`rsync -av test.txt 192.168.1.1::modulename/test.txt`

where modulename is a module you've defined in your config file. If you actually want to use your ssh keys to secure your connection, you will need to have an ssh daemon running. See [the cwRsync FAQ](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/11317) for more details.