# Disable SSH on cwrsyncserver?

Tags: backup, ssh, rsync, cygwin

I installed cwrsyncserver, the rsyncd.conf makes no mention of ssh and I am not specifying to use ssh when I connect. Yet, the error I get is connection to port 22 refused.

My rsyncd.conf is thus:

```
use chroot = false
strict modes = false
hosts allow = *
log file = rsyncd.log

# Module definitions
# Remember cygwin naming conventions : c:\work becomes /cygwin/c/work
#
[test]
path = /cygdrive/c/users/jay/desktop/xxxxx
read only = false
transfer logging = yes
```

And I am trying to test the setup with this command:

```
rsync --verbose -tz --stats --progress  '/cygdrive/c/users/jay/Desktop/1/1.txt' josh@localhost:"/test.txt"
```

I then get the error about being able to connect to port 22.

How can I specifically not make use of ssh?

Comment: Sorry about my comment, I misread/misunderstood what you were trying to do.  The ssh thing is a red herring here.  As @justarobert mentioned, it's a simple syntax error on your test case.  This is cause it to use the "traditional" rsync behavior, which uses ssh as a transport, as opposed to the rsync-server model.  I still like the idea of using ssh as the transport for the security aspect, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/252499/trouble-with-cwrsync-on-windows/252610). With your existing setup, you'll want to use something like

```
rsync --verbose -tz --stats --progress  '/cygdrive/c/users/jay/Desktop/1/1.txt' localhost::test/test.txt
```

The double colon tells the rsync client to contact the rsync daemon directly, without using a remote shell. Consult the man page for information on how to set up a password for this module. However, @Chris is right that this method is not very secure, especially if you have read-write modules.